# Как отсортировать JSONArray по ключу в JSONObject?

Tags: java, android, json, compare

Получаю такого вида JSONArray:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Иван",
        "image": "/images/category/",
        "status": 1,
        "totalMessages": 5
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Сергей",
        "image": "/images/category/",
        "status": 1,
        "totalMessages": 120
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Вася",
        "image": "/images/category/",
        "status": 1,
        "totalMessages": 40
    }
]
```

Как получаю?

```
    String json = JsonUtils.getJSONString("http://mysite.com/simple?data");
    JSONArray data = new JSONArray(json);
    JSONObject objJson = null;

    // Попытался здесь сортировать.. но сортирует неверно. 
    data = JsonUtils.sort(data, new Comparator() {
        public int compare(Object a, Object b) {
            JSONObject ja = (JSONObject) a;
            JSONObject jb = (JSONObject) b;
            return ja.optString("totalMessages", "").toUpperCase().compareTo(jb.optString("totalMessages", "").toLowerCase());
        }
    });

      // Здесь уже всё прогоняю и заполняю ArrayList данными...
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
            objJson = data.getJSONObject(i);
            String id = objJson.getString("id");
            String name = objJson.getString("name");
            String image = objJson.getString("image");
            String status = objJson.getString("status");
            String totalMessages = objJson.getString("totalMessages");
            myArrayList.add(new Item(id, name, image, status, totalMessages));

        }
```

Как сделать такой результат на выходе? Чтобы сортировал по ключу `totalMessages` , не смотря на `id`, `name`, `image` и `status` ключи? :

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Иван",
        "image": "/images/category/",
        "status": 1,
        "totalMessages": 5
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Вася",
        "image": "/images/category/",
        "status": 1,
        "totalMessages": 40
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Сергей",
        "image": "/images/category/",
        "status": 1,
        "totalMessages": 120
    }
]
```

Заранее благодарен, кто поможет разобраться, что я не так делаю :)

P.S: вот содержимое `JSONArray sort ()`

```
public static JSONArray sort(JSONArray array, Comparator c){
    List asList = new ArrayList(array.length());
    for (int i=0; i<array.length(); i++){
        asList.add(array.opt(i));
    }
    Collections.sort(asList, c);
    JSONArray  res = new JSONArray();
    for (Object o : asList){
        res.put(o);
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: В компараторе: `return Integer.compare(ja.optInt("totalMessages"), jb.optInt("totalMessages")));` . Только у Вас сейчас почему-то обратный порядок - если что поменяйте местами параметры в `Integer.compare(a <=> b)`. И ещё - зачем лишние преобразования? Лучше сортировать готовый java-список `myArrayList` после заполнения

Comment: Большое спасибо, получилось!. Разместите ответом, приму = )

Comment: Ну у меня там всего 40 объектов в массиве, и получаю я его один раз всего лишь , больше не работая с ним), не думаю что очень критично по производительности ударит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Результат странный потому что Вы сортируете значения в строковом представлении. Чтобы сделать правильный порядок нужно сортировать в числовом:

```
data = JsonUtils.sort(data, new Comparator() {
        public int compare(Object a, Object b) {
            JSONObject ja = (JSONObject) a;
            JSONObject jb = (JSONObject) b;
            return  Integer.compare(ja.optInt("totalMessages"), jb.optInt("totalMessages")));
```

Только у Вас сейчас почему-то обратный порядок - если что поменяйте местами параметры в `Integer.compare(a <=> b)`